# How to pass a service header when calling a WCF Service on a WinRT app

Tags: wcf, service, header, windows-runtime

I got two projects on my solution - a Console Application project and a WinRT project.

I need to consume a WCF Service, what I can perfectly do through my Console Application simply using the following lines:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    var client  = new ServiceReference1.ComeAndGoClient("BasicHttpBinding_IComeAndGo");
    var header = new ServiceReference1.ServiceHeader{ AccountID = "a1", DeviceID = "d1" };
    var res = client.GetEmployees(ref header, "");
}
```

The problem is - I'm not finding out how can I send the same service header (AccountID and DeviceID) when calling the same method through my WinRT app.

```
var client = new ServiceReference1.ComeAndGoClient(ServiceReference1.ComeAndGoClient.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IComeAndGo);

public async Task LoadData()
{
    var sessions = await client.GetEmployeesAsync("");
}
```

Note: On my WinRT project I don't have any GetEmployeesAsync method which gets ServiceHeader as a parameter like I have GetEmployees on my Console Application project. 
I had added the same service reference to both projects, though.